# Why is SwiftUI not hiding my status bar on this fullScreenCover?

Tags: swiftui, statusbar

My code is below. Should `.statusBar(hidden: true)` be in a different place? Does it depend on some `@Environment` I'm unaware of?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowingFullScreenModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Show Modal")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 180, height: 44)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .onTapGesture {
                isShowingFullScreenModal = true
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingFullScreenModal) {
                Color.green
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isShowingFullScreenModal = false
                    }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct GreenCover: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.green
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The code above now works as intended. (using Xcode 14.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
.onTapGesture {
    isShowingFullScreenModal = true
}
.statusBar(hidden: isShowingFullScreenModal)                // << here !!
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingFullScreenModal) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in our application, we need to hide the status bar, navigation bar, and other things and only show the content we want to display. To hide status bar in our iOS application using swift language we need to go through very basic steps.

**Method 1**

In your `info.plist` file itself, add another key called `Status bar is initially hidden` and set it to YES.

What I've noticed with this method is that, the status bar is hidden only when the application is launched.

**Method 2**

Go to your app delegate file, and add this line of code: `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true`

This was deprecated on iOS 13.

**Method 3**

You can add this line of code as well, and the status bar will be hidden.

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
.statusBar(hidden: true)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is helpful at all though, if you mean to answer my question. It's just a general explanation. My original code does have `.statusBar(hidden: true)`. If, under point 3, you mean to add specifically `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`, then it would be helpful to say that explicitly. Or did you mean that both lines must be added? In that order? My code does have `.ignoresSafeArea(.all)` under the Z-stack. Are you saying the `ignores...` code must precede the `status bar hidden...` code? I'm really sorry, but I don't see how this answers my question at all. Can you be more clear?